# This webpage has a redirect loop issue

Tags: login, wp-redirect

I want to redirect non logged in users to page id = 2 which have registration form.

```
    function checkLogged()
{
    $pg = get_permalink();
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_front_page() && $pg != home_url('/?page_id=2'))
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/?page_id=2'));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'checkLogged');
```

Is this code correct ? I am getting

> This webpage has a redirect loop The webpage at
>   http://abc.com/dsdd_wordpress/?page_id=2 has resulted in too many
>   redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party
>   cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server
>   configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code instead of above code :

```
function checkLogged()
{

if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_front_page() && 2 != get_queried_object_id())
{
    wp_redirect(home_url('/?page_id=2'));
    exit;
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'checkLogged');
```